# Create a vector out of a sum of personalized arrays

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with multiple texts with keywords that have a unique vector. My question is how could one create a vector for every text as the sum of the vectors of the keywords found in each text.

Here is an example of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

text_df={'text':['this is a text', 'this too', 'hello text', 'no key word here']}

text_df=pd.DataFrame(data=text_df)

dict_df=pd.DataFrame(data={'word':['this','too','text'], 'vector':[np.array([1,0,0], dtype=object),np.array([0,1,0], dtype=object), np.array([0,0,1], dtype=object)]})

dict_df

pat = '|'.join(dict_df['word'].tolist())


text_df['matchwords'] = text_df['text'].str.extractall(f"({pat})"
                                  ,flags=re.IGNORECASE)\
                            .groupby(level=0)[0].agg(','.join)



text_df
```

The output desired would be a new column with a vector for each row displaying the sum of the vectors of the key words in the dictionary.

For example the first row would have a vector [1,0,1]

Is there a way to create an array depending on the key words a given text, which one could sum using np.sum?

Comment: Would `text_df['matchsum'] = text_df['text'].str.extractall(f"({pat})",flags=re.IGNORECASE).groupby(level=0)[0].count()` do what you want? Just adapts your code to return the count of the matches (ie sum of the vector) instead of concatenating them

Comment: @JoshFriedlander i need the outpu to bet a 1x3 vector, which is the sum of the n number of vectors depending on how many key words are in a text